# How to applied a user defined function to each of the numpy array elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to apply a function to each of the element of my numpy array. 
I did some thing like this; but it still print the original array. What might be the problem?

```
def my_func(k):
    3.15+ k*12**45+16

arr = np.array([12,45,45],[12,88,63])
my_func(arr)
print (arr)
```

Comment: wouldn't just `3.15 + arr*12**45+16` work?

Comment: Do you maybe want to return something from that function and use `arr` instead of `ar` and reassign to `arr`?

Comment: it does but what i have a much more complex function which take as a parameters a single value but i want to apply it to all the array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
def my_func(k):
    return 3.15 + k * 12 ** 45 + 16

arr = np.array([[12, 45, 45], [12, 88, 63]])
print my_func(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[4.388714385610605e+49 1.6457678946039768e+50 1.6457678946039768e+50]
 [4.388714385610605e+49 3.218390549447777e+50 2.3040750524455676e+50]]
```

The problem is that you don't return a value from your function. Then you don't define correctly the data for `np.array`. Finally, you don't set the `my_func`'s result in a variable.

Comment: It works. Thank you. I did not save the results. in another array. Thank you

Comment: @  JuniorCompressor i have a problem tough, when i try it on a vector, i have an error like this : TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
import numpy as np

def my_func(k):
    return 3.15 + k*12**45+16

arr = np.array(([12,45,45],[12,88,63]))
print (arr)
arr = my_func(arr)
print (arr)
```

you get this:

```
[[12 45 45]
 [12 88 63]]
[[4.388714385610605e+49 1.6457678946039768e+50 1.6457678946039768e+50]
 [4.388714385610605e+49 3.218390549447777e+50 2.3040750524455676e+50]]
```